# rationale behind multi-layer networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I recently read that a feed forward neural network with a single hidden layer can represent any continuous function to great precision ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)).
Then how can we justify adding more that one hidden layer to our network ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rationale is that the number of neurones you need to use for approximating any given contiguous function decreases as you add subsequent layers.
See Colah's [Deep Learning, NLP, and Representations](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-NLP-RNNs-Representations/) for a more in-depth explanation.